# How to generate a winform application with delphi and .Net respectively?

Tags: .net, winforms, delphi

I need to make a choice between the two languages,both of which are new to me.

I want to choose the simpler one.

Also,please mention about the setups needed to run the programme.

Comment: You've asked for demos.  What exactly would you like to see a demo for?

Comment: Well you could always try Delphi.NET ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Net is a platform, not a language.

If you choose .Net, you would then need to choose which language to write in.  The two most popular ones are C# and VB .Net, and I recommend C#.

If you choose .Net, you should install a version of Visual Studio (the [Express Editions](http://www.microsoft.com/exPress/) are free).  Your users will need to install a version of the .Net framework (either 2.0, 3.0, or 3.5).  Many users will already have it; Vista includes 3.0, and Windows 7 includes 3.5.

Comment: It should be noted that Windows 7 includes all versions of .NET up to and including 3.5.

Comment: Huh? Delphi comes with its own IDE - so is Delphi a real choice then?

Comment: But .Net seems more up to dated.Can you provide a demo?Also,is Express Editions limited in functionality?

Comment: Yes, the Express editions are limited in functionality compared to standard and pro editions. Microsoft provides feature grids that show which functionalality is support by which edition - just google or search on Microsoft's web sites for feature charts comparing visual studio editions. You should, however, be fine as long as you want to develop pure WinForms applications.

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend going Delphi.

It's a veteran language, which produces fast (faster than .net) native (no need to install any runtime) win32 applications. The designer of delphi is much better (at least for me) than the VS one. The number of standard components provided in Delphi is bigger than the one in VS.

Delphi is an absolute monster when it comes to databases. it comes with drivers for 11 different databases (mysql, ms sql, firebird, interbase, ibm db2, oracle etc) + you can get drivers for any database you want.

It will allow you to write Native applications, windows services, and basically anything you want. Except device drivers (afaik neitehr .net can do that) , so if your intentions aren't to write drivers for a scanner or smth then I'd say "Go delphi".

And there was a quote about delphi and vb which said (maybe it's irrevelant in this topic )

"VB makes easy applications easier, Delphi makes hard applications easier".

Oh and both Delphi and C# are designed by the same person.

Comment: Here's a list of some quality Delphi applications: 
http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Good_Quality_Applications_Built_With_Delphi

As for the "demo"
Demo for what?

here are some sites you can use to get you going

http://delphi.about.com/
stackoverflow.com :D
forums.embarcadero.com
blogs.embarcadero.com

And if you want cross compilation check Lazarus. (Try-to-be Delphi Clone) which can compile to a lot of platforms (http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Platform_list)

Comment: Anders Hejlsberg is the chief Architect of the initial versions of Delphi, and C#.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders_Hejlsberg

Answer (score 0):

SLaks points out correctly that .NET is not a language, but a framework. I would like to add that your choice depends heavily on what the application's supposed to do.

For example: if you need to do a lot of database work with SQL Server, .NET provides some very good and easy-to-use stuff. Also, COM(+) components and Windows Services can be easily created with .NET. You can, however, do that with Delphi as well.

If you have to call Windows APIs all the time, Delphi (I suppose you're talking about the Win32 version) makes that easier, while through P/Invoke you can do the same with .NET, too.

If your application should not depend on any framework, you'd need to do Delphi Win32 development. If it does not matter, I'd always suggest to use .NET with C#. If you already know C or C++, learning C# is not too hard. With the help of the Mono project it would be easy to port your .NET application to Linux/MacOS as long as you rely on framework standard APIs.

But - as d4nt commented above - things would be easier if you gave us more detail...

Comment: Can I connect to MySQL with .Net?

Comment: Great,can you provide a demo?I'm downloading .Net now.